# Привязка ScrolBar в WPF

Tags: wpf

Есть 8 однотипных коллекций. Не придумал ничего умнее как поместить их в 8 ListBox. Айтемы естественно отображаю кастомно, т.е. нарисовал темплейт для них. 
Как сделать, чтобы при прокрутке скролбара на одном листбоксе, происходила прокрутка и на остальных? Или как адекватно забиндить все в 1 листбокс?

Comment: В одну коллекцию нельзя собрать? 8 сущностей в один класс и его в одну коллекцию

Comment: Можно сделать поле в сущности что-то типа "номер ряда". Но как тогда адекватно отобразить это все в листбоксе? Это должно быть похоже на 8 стопок (стэков). Т.е. могут быть пустые столбы, все столбы могут иметь разное кол-во элементов. В общем как то так: 
http://www.picshare.ru/view/8125315/

Comment: В таком случае возьмите ItemsControl с горизонтальной ориентацией, в него поместите ItemsControl'ы с вертикальной ориентацией, в которых уже будут отображаться коллекции

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Набросал вам пример.

Простой класс-стопка, который содержит заголовок и коллекцию сущностей:

```
class Pile
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Привязываем коллекцию наших стопок (если у вас `MVVM` - вы легко сделаете это через `Binding`):

```
itemsControl.ItemsSource = new List<Pile>
{
    new Pile
    {
        Header = "Header 1",
        Items = new List<string>
        {
            "Item 1",
            "Item 2",
            "Item 3",
            "Item 4"
        }
    },
    new Pile
    {
        Header = "Header 2",
        Items = new List<string>
        {
            "Item 5",
            "Item 6"
        }
    },
    new Pile
    {
        Header = "Header 3",
        Items = new List<string>()
    },
    new Pile
    {
        Header = "Header 4",
        Items = new List<string>
        {
            "Item 7",
            "Item 8",
            "Item 9",
            "Item 10",
            "Item 11",
            "Item 12",
            "Item 13",
            "Item 14",
            "Item 15"
        }
    }
};
```

Разметка содержимого окна:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="HeaderTextBlock">
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2.5"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="ItemTextBlock">
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2.5"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl Name="itemsControl">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="1" Margin="2.5"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"
                               Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlock}"/>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                                           Style="{StaticResource ItemTextBlock}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Я применил стилизованные `TextBlock'и`, если вы собираетесь как-то обрабатывать клики по ним или что-то еще, возможно удобнее будет использовать кнопки.

Получилось вот что:

[image: Piles2]